# After purchasing a used copy, can a Battle.net account be reset?

Tags: starcraft-2

My buddy recently bought a used copy of Starcraft 2 from a friend and wanted to make himself an account.  If he has the existing account information will Blizzard reset his battle.net account for a fee?  (Letting him pick his own name and new stats?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Blizzard does not reset battle.net accounts, and takes action (i.e., disabling them) against those who try to sell their old accounts to others.

To get access to multi-player battle.net (and a virgin starcraft 2 profile), your buddy will need a new starcraft 2 account key. His used copy is perfectly fine if he's only interested in the single-player campaign, however. (Though no achievements will be eligible to be earned)